# Treemap Causes Uncaught Type Error: Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, sapui5, treemap

I'm creating a SAPUI5 prototype version of a system that currently exists in Silverlight.

Within the current Silverlight application we have a page which contains a Data Table, a bar chart and a Treemap which all display different representations of the same data.

In SAPUI5, I've replicated the Data Table and Bar Chart successfully, but I cannot get the Treemap to display, all I get is the Uncaught Type Error: Undefined is not a function error on the line where I try to create the Treemap.

```
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(
            "../../../services/PCPVCarlineModelYear.xsodata/",
            false);
    
var treemapDataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({

            dimensions : [ {
            axis : 1, // must be 1 for x-axis. 2 for y-axis
            name : 'Carline',
            value : "{Carline}"
        }],

        measures : [ {
            group : 1,
            name : 'NumberOfVINs',
            value : '{NumberOfVINs}'
        }],

        data : {
            path : "/PCPVCarlineModelYear"
        }
    });
    

    var oTreemap = new sap.viz.ui5.types.Treemap({
        dataset : treemapDataset
    });
    
    oTreemap.setModel(oModel);
    
    return oTreemap;
```

The Undefined is not a function error occurs on the `var oTreemap = new sap.viz.ui5.Treemap({` line.

If I change the code from `Treemap` to `Bar`, then it displays a Bar chart correctly, just not the Treemap.

Also, with the `index.html` page, I have the following script block declared in order to load the correct libraries:

```
    <script src="/sap/ui5/1/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui- libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table,sap.viz,sap.viz.ui5"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_hcb"
            data-sap-ui-modules="sap.ui.core.plugin.DeclarativeSupport">
    </script>
```

Can anyone suggest what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks very much,

Martyn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of SAPUI5 are you using? 
Version 1.14 has the `Treemap`, 1.12 doesn't.

You could run the same test as here: [Link](http://jsbin.com/aku-test-treemap-exists/1/edit)
(click on "run with JS")

The example returns the code of the `Treemap` constructor - what does it return when you load your own copy/sap-ui-core.js of UI5?

Or alternatively, instead of loading UI5 from your own server, you could try loading it from [Link](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js) (just like in my jsbin snippet)
Does the Treemap work then?

Regards
Andreas

Comment: Thank you very much Andreas, my server is a HANA dev server running in AWS as it is only running version 1.12, despite me having the 1.14 client development tools installed in HANA Studio. I can't see how to upgrade the version of the SAPUI5 runtime that is running on a HANA server so I believe I am stuck with 1.12 for the foreseeable future. Thanks very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Give a cross check with the case , in JavaScript the uppercase and lower case are treated differently.

I was facing the same problem the mistake was instead of `sap.m.Page()` i was writing 
`sap.m.page();`